# Line break breaks scientific notation

Tags: microsoft-word, linebreaks, notation

My text contains a numerical value with scientific notation ("7∙10-5 mm Hg at 25 °C", with "-5" in superscript). Word insists on a line break between "-" and "5" when the expression occurs at the end of line. Anyone has an idea how to stop such behaviour?  (I cannot use a workaround through insertion of the expression as equation; non-breaking space to force the whole value to one line does not work.)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate your issue, for me it works correctly.

The problem in your case probably is that you don't have the proper **minus-hyphen character** in your text, but a [dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Hyphens_and_dashes).

Just delete the dash and type a proper minus sign.

In below picture first example has a dash, while second one contains the minus sign:

[image]